# how to abort a long running objective c operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, cancellation

I have a long running operation with a bunch of `"_isCancelled"` flags

```
// long running code
if (_isCancelled)
  return;

// more code
if (_isCancelled)
  return;

// more code

if (_isCancelled)
  return;

// etc.
```

but it would be much cleaner and easier to add more "long running code" if I could somehow abort the operation from an "outside" listening thread

for instance

```
-(void)longRunningAsyncOperation
{
  @try {
   // long running operation
  } @catch
  {
   // if aborted just return
  }
}

-(void)cancelOperation
{
// raise an exception on a "listening" thread
}
```

Any thoughts on this approach? is it possible?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113268/how-to-cancel-nsblockoperation

Comment: still looks like they keep checking for nil in each iteration