# Cancel actions in dispatch_async when they're no longer needed

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I have a `UIViewController` that does the following in `viewDidLoad`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    items = [[DataFetcher sharedInstance] getItems handler:^(NSArray *currentItems){
        if (currentItems.count % 30 == 0) { //don't wait for all the items to be ready show by chunks of 30
            items = currentItems;
            [tableView reloadData];
        }
        items = currentItems;
    }];//Pretty complex call that takes some time to finish there is WebService calls, data parsing, storing some results ...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [tableView reloadData];
    });
});
```

What I need to do is to stop `getItems` when I pop this viewController. It's pointless and it takes CPU Time and energy (This call may take up to a minute on some cases).

I am assuming I should be doing this in `viewWillDisappear` but how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSBlockOperation`. Periodically check if it's been cancelled, and stop doing work if it has been:

```
- (void)getItemsWithHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *currentItems))handler {
    self.operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        if (self.operation.isCancelled) {
            return;
        }

        // Do something expensive

        if (self.operation.isCancelled) {
            return;
        }

        // Do something else expensive

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            if (self.operation.isCancelled) {
                return;
            }

            // Do expensive things in a loop
        }
    }];
}

- (void) cancelGetItemsRequest {
    [self.operation cancel];
    self.operation = nil;
}
```

Alternatively, you can put a bunch of `NSBlockOperation`s in an `NSOperationQueue`. You can set dependencies for the work, and cancel the entire queue at once if you want.

Comment: Note that strongly capturing `self` in an operation also owned by `self` creates a retain cycle. This example clears the dependency in the cancellation case, but not in the successful completion case.

Comment: Yeah, I should've mentioned that. Thanks for pointing it out. See [this question for further discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8113268/1445366).

Answer (score 0):

Cancelling asynchronous operations is nicely supported in NSOperation and NSOperationQueue, but it's quite a bit more complicated. In any case, your asynchronous code has to check from time to time whether it is cancelled or should still continue.

Best thing is to have a property "cancelled" somewhere, that you set when you don't want any more work to be done, and whenever you try to do more work, you check that property.

Comment: I think it would actually be *less* complicated with [`NSBlockOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSBlockOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: (It doesn't even require an operation queue, and already has a cancelled property.)