# NsoperationQueue Cancel all operations is not cancelled until it finishes the operation

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue, cancellation

In my view i have image view, the data for image view comes form Url, the images are around 1-3 MB .
If the user Swipes then i want to load the next image, Every thing works fine if swiped slowly, But when i swiped Fastly I want to Cancel the previous operation and start with new url.

For Ex. if user swipes 4 times if the operations for 2nd and 3rd images is in the middle, i want to cancel those and start downloading 4 th image

But now In the place of 4th image I’m getting first 2nd image follows 3rd and then 4 th image appears.

Here is my sample code

```
- (void)handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)aSwipeGestureRecognizer {


    [BackgroundOperation cancelAllOperations];  // To cancel previous one 


    [self performSelector:@selector(LoadImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];


}

-(void)LoadImage
{
    BackgroundOperation=[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];  


    imgvww.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"loader.png"]; // Place holder    till download finishes 


   [BackgroundOperation addOperationWithBlock:^
     {
         UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.ItemDetails objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"ImageUrl"]]]];  // Getting data from URL 

         [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{


             imgvww.image=img;  //Adding to image view after completion 


         }];

     }];
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please make an effort to format your code such that other people can read it.

Comment: Are you recreating `BackgroundOperation` everytime an image needs to be loaded (with `BackgroundOperation=[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Canceling an operation merely sets its `isCancelled` Flag to true.

You're responsible for checking to see if your operation has been cancelled, before it starts to run (or while it is running, if it is a long-running operation).

You can [check if your operation is cancelled within an operation block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13030641/4151918) but I'd recommend subclassing, instead of using a block.

Comment: I didn't understand clearly, It seems v have to check  isCancelled.But Im confused where to check it in my code

Comment: Im not using Nsoperation, It seems isCancelled exist for nsoperation

Comment: `NSBlockOperation` is a subclass of `NSOperation`.  It can be cancelled.  Check the link again and see how it captures the (weak)  blockOperation, so isCancelled can be checked within the block.  If you're still not sure how to do this, [check this detailed article](http://nghiatran.me/advanced-issues-the-right-way-to-load-content-in-backgrounds-thread-with-tableview/) which also cancels block operations.

Comment: K i will try with this link, But Im not using ARC, So whts the alternative for     __weak NSBlockOperation *weakOperation = loadImageOperation;

Comment: Replace __weak with __block.

Comment: you should be using ARC. why don't you?

Comment: @ yar1vn V started the project without ARC when v r supporting lower versions. But v r working on it to support ARC

Comment: @PetahChristian Is there any way to pause and resume  the operation?

Comment: @siva you can suspend the queue, but it will not pause any operations that have already started.  If you need more sophisticated control over the download, you need to use a different approach, like what DBoyer suggested.

Comment: @PetahChristian I will go through that, Thanks for Info

Comment: @siva Don't forget to upvote other answers.  You've gotten some good help from several people!

Answer (score 7):

Calling `cancelAllOperations` on an `NSOperationQueue` will simply call `cancel` on each of its operations. If the `NSOperation` does not override `cancel` then its never going to get cancelled.

There is no concept of cancelling an `NSBlockOperation` once it has started. The block simply executes and thats that.

If you want to specify special cancel behaviour (like cancelling your image download) you need to subclass `NSOperation` and override `cancel`.

There are many examples of this in `AFNetworking` or `SDWebImage`

To cancel an image download you need to wrap up an `NSURLSesionDownloadTask` in an `NSOperation` and then override `cancel` to call `cancel` on the `NSURLSesionDownloadTask`

Comment: no need to subclass an NSOperation to be able to cancel, it's possible to do it within the performed block

Comment: That will cancel the block yes but once the image download has started there is no stopping it by simply using dataWithContentsOfURL

Comment: `cancel` is not actually called on all the operations, it just sets `isCancelled` to YES

Answer (score 3):

Canceling the operation will only update its `isCancelled` property to `YES`.
To be able to cancel the operation, you should do the following:

```
NSBlockOperation * op = [NSBlockOperation new];
__weak NSBlockOperation * weakOp = op; // Use a weak reference to avoid a retain cycle
[op addExecutionBlock:^{
    // Put this code between whenever you want to allow an operation to cancel
    // For example: Inside a loop, before a large calculation, before saving/updating data or UI, etc.
    if (weakOp.isCancelled) return;

    // Do something..
];
```